# The differential of a smooth map on manifold at points of local maxima

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I have a differentiable function $f:M \to \mathbb{R}$ where $M$ is a smooth manifold. If $p \in M $ is a point of local maxima, that is I have an open set $V \subset M$, $p \in V$, so that $f(p)\geq f(x), \forall x \in V$ , I need to show that $f_*|_p (v) = 0, \forall v \in T_p(M)$.

I tried using a chart $(U, \phi)$ around $p$ containing $V$, and then the function $f \small \;o \; \phi^{-1}:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, of course the domain being more specific. Then I tried to use the fact that this map gives a zero map as the derivative at $p$, but I am not sure whether I am on the right track. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I think your inequality should read $f(p)\geq f(x)$. As to answering the question, do you know the interpretation of tangent vectors as derivations?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. Yes, I do.

Comment: Ok, I am not able to see the connection here. Could you elaborate a bit more??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that $(f_*)_p(X_p)=X_p(f)$, where we treat $X_p\in T_pM$ as a derivation on the ring of smooth functions. Therefore, showing that $(f_*)_p(X_p)=0$ whenever $f$ reaches a local maximum is the same as showing that the directional derivative of $f$ in any given direction is $0$ at $p$. Think you can take it from there?

Comment: Thanks, yeah I see how I can bring in the derivation interpretation. So now I just use the fact that as $X_p(f) = \sum a_i \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}|_p$, which is 0 at points of maxima?

Comment: Indeed. Great job!

Comment: Thanks, I should have seen that without so many hints to be honest.

Comment: @Vishesh -- Truth be told, it just takes practice to know which interpretation is best for a specific problem. I had the same problem when I started. If you use Spivak's *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry*, then Chapter 3 of Volume 1 is a great chapter to bookmark.

Comment: Sure, will do, appreciate the suggestions.